# Присвоение переменной результата запроса

Tags: sql

Есть таблица студентов(id,name,averageMark) и таблица оценок(idStudent,idSubject,mark). Как мне присвоить averageMark из таблицы студентов результат запроса SELECT AVG(mark) FROM marks?

Comment: Не должно быть в таблице студентов поля `averageMark` - так получаются денормализованные данные.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov мне кажется, иногда имеет смысл хранить среднее значение (как кеш), если оценок действительно много, а запрос на получение среднего значения выполняется слишком часто

Comment: Если и делать что-то подобное, то нужно использовать триггер или смотреть в сторону материализованного представления

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пусть таблица студентов называется `Students`, а таблица оценок - `StudentMarks`, тогда запрос будет следующий:

```
UPDATE s
SET s.averageMark = m.averageMark
FROM Students s
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        sm.idStudent,
        AVG(sm.mark) as averageMark
    FROM
        StudentMarks sm
    GROUP BY
        sm.idStudent
) m
ON m.idStudent = s.id
```

Запрос выполнит обновление столбца `averageMark` для **всех** студентов